# Images stuck in one position

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let me start of by saying that I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS.

I'm creating a website for a company I work at, the website will contain all information of all locations of said company.

I will use the Netherlands as an example.

[I've added a map for each country that displays all locations with "pings"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MFWS.png).

As you can see, the "pings" are where they are supposed to be, but when I resize the window or drag the window to another screen which is smaller then 1920x1080, [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPecw.png)

I don't really know how to fix this

I've added my code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Netherlands Locations</title>
</head>
<body>

<center><h1 style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:30;font-style:normal;text-decoration: none;"><a href="file:///C:/Users/MTA/Documents/Site2/SiteEwalsLocations2.html" style="color: #000000"><b>HOME</b></h1></a>

<style type="text/css">
    
    }
    .responsive 
    {
         max-width: 20px;
         height: auto;
    }
    .Netherlands3
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .Ping1
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 610px;
        left: 1075px;
    }
    .Ping2
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 590px;
        left: 1060px;
    }
    .Ping3
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:385px;
        left:1194px;
    }
    .Ping4
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:400px;
        left:840px;
    }
</style>

<img src="Netherlands3.png" alt="Netherlands" height="730" width="700" usemap="#Netherlands3"></a>

<map name="Netherlands3">

<style type="text/css"></style>

    <!-- Tegelen. -->
    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ari%C3%ABnsstraat+61,+5931+HM+Tegelen/@51.3507443,6.1482531,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!1m3!11m2!2sL57brsHAatVbQdnqSsRwtDw-ymHUUQ!3e3!3m4!1s0x47c750011bdd6129:0x13a1103e35402205!8m2!3d51.3507443!4d6.1504418" target="_blank"><img src="pinggood.png" class="Ping1"/ height="30" width="20" onmouseover="this.src='pinggood2.png'" onmouseout="this.src= 'pinggood.png' " class=".responsive"></a>

    <!-- Maasbree. -->
    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Olivier+van+Noortweg+7,+5928+LX+Maasbree/@51.3428879,6.1045779,12z/data=!4m9!1m3!11m2!2sL57brsHAatVbQdnqSsRwtDw-ymHUUQ!3e3!3m4!1s0x47c745c94041f7f5:0x901eaac368a5573b!8m2!3d51.3921233!4d6.0645604" target="_blank"><img src="pinggood.png" class="Ping2"/ height="30" width="20" onmouseover="this.src='pinggood2.png'" onmouseout="this.src= 'pinggood.png' " class=".sticky"></a>

    <!-- Oldenzaal. -->
    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ewals+Cargo+Care+B.V./@52.2932725,6.9211237,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!1m3!11m2!2sL57brsHAatVbQdnqSsRwtDw-ymHUUQ!3e3!3m4!1s0x47b816dfb82cd1c3:0x8853cf9983c82627!8m2!3d52.2932725!4d6.9233124" target="_blank"><img src="pinggood.png" class="Ping3"/ height="30" width="20" onmouseover="this.src='pinggood2.png'" onmouseout="this.src= 'pinggood.png' " class=".img-responsive"></a>

    <!-- Rozenburg. -->
    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ewals+Cargo+Care+B.V./@52.2731607,4.7347315,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!1m3!11m2!2sL57brsHAatVbQdnqSsRwtDw-ymHUUQ!3e3!3m4!1s0x47c5e7f7130ab605:0x2820e78f4b3fffe9!8m2!3d52.2731607!4d4.7369202" target="_blank"><img src="pinggood.png" class="Ping4"/ height="30" width="20" onmouseover="this.src='pinggood2.png'" onmouseout="this.src= 'pinggood.png' " class=".img-responsive"></a>


<style type="text/css">
    
    <EWALS CARGO CARE>
    
    {}
    .InformatieTegelen
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 800px;
        left: 600px;
    }
    .InformatieMaasbree
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 800px;
        left: 800px;
    }
    .InformatieOldenzaal
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 800px;
        left: 1000px;
    }
    .InformatieRozenburg
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 800px;
        left: 1200px;
    }
</style>

<p style="font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;font-style:normal;"><a href="file:///C:/Users/MTA/Documents/Site2/NED/InfoTEG.html" style="color: black" class="InformatieTegelen">Informatie Tegelen</a></p>
<p style="font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;font-style:normal;"><a href="file:///C:/Users/MTA/Documents/Site2/NED/InfoMAA.html" style="color: black" class="InformatieMaasbree">Informatie Maasbree</a></p>
<p style="font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;font-style:normal;"><a href="file:///C:/Users/MTA/Documents/Site2/NED/InfoODZ.html" style="color: black" class="InformatieOldenzaal">Informatie Oldenzaal</a></p>
<p style="font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;font-style:normal;"><a href="file:///C:/Users/MTA/Documents/Site2/NED/InfoROZ.html" style="color: black" class="InformatieRozenburg">Informatie Rozenburg</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like the position absolute is the cause of this issue. you are using the top and left with pixel which means it always stay the same distance from the top and from the left no matter what resolution you will have. i would put the image as a bg of a div, the div will be position relative so all the pings inside will be absolute to the limits of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did is to wrap your everything in a div.(class mapBg , you can chose better name)
the div is with the size we want the map to be,
the map img is getting width: 100% and height 100%.
then the pings can be position absolute, the top and left will refer to the limits of the wrapper div.
here is an example.
HTML

```
<div class="mapBg">

<img src="Netherlands.png" alt="Netherlands" style="height:100%; width:100%" usemap="#Netherlands3"></a>

<map name="Netherlands3">

    <!-- Tegelen. -->
    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ari%C3%ABnsstraat+61,+5931+HM+Tegelen/@51.3507443,6.1482531,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!1m3!11m2!2sL57brsHAatVbQdnqSsRwtDw-ymHUUQ!3e3!3m4!1s0x47c750011bdd6129:0x13a1103e35402205!8m2!3d51.3507443!4d6.1504418" target="_blank"><img src="pinggood.png" class="Ping1"/ height="30" width="20" onmouseover="this.src='pinggood2.png'" onmouseout="this.src= 'pinggood.png' " class=".responsive"></a>

    <!-- Maasbree. -->
    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Olivier+van+Noortweg+7,+5928+LX+Maasbree/@51.3428879,6.1045779,12z/data=!4m9!1m3!11m2!2sL57brsHAatVbQdnqSsRwtDw-ymHUUQ!3e3!3m4!1s0x47c745c94041f7f5:0x901eaac368a5573b!8m2!3d51.3921233!4d6.0645604" target="_blank"><img src="pinggood.png" class="Ping2"/ height="30" width="20" onmouseover="this.src='pinggood2.png'" onmouseout="this.src= 'pinggood.png' " class=".sticky"></a>

    <!-- Oldenzaal. -->
    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ewals+Cargo+Care+B.V./@52.2932725,6.9211237,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!1m3!11m2!2sL57brsHAatVbQdnqSsRwtDw-ymHUUQ!3e3!3m4!1s0x47b816dfb82cd1c3:0x8853cf9983c82627!8m2!3d52.2932725!4d6.9233124" target="_blank"><img src="pinggood.png" class="Ping3"/ height="30" width="20" onmouseover="this.src='pinggood2.png'" onmouseout="this.src= 'pinggood.png' " class=".img-responsive"></a>

    <!-- Rozenburg. -->
    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ewals+Cargo+Care+B.V./@52.2731607,4.7347315,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!1m3!11m2!2sL57brsHAatVbQdnqSsRwtDw-ymHUUQ!3e3!3m4!1s0x47c5e7f7130ab605:0x2820e78f4b3fffe9!8m2!3d52.2731607!4d4.7369202" target="_blank"><img src="pinggood.png" class="Ping4"/ height="30" width="20" onmouseover="this.src='pinggood2.png'" onmouseout="this.src= 'pinggood.png' " class=".img-responsive"></a>

</div>
```

css:

```
.mapBg{
  position: relative;
  width: 730px;
  height: 700px;
}
.Ping1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
}
.Ping2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 160px;
}
.Ping3{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/gOwjrpW)